According to relativity, does spinning a top throw the heavens apart, or pull them together, or do nothing to them, or something else?
When I spin a spinning top on my table, we know that the components of the top are placed in tension due to the binary relation of centrifugal forces between opposing masses on opposing sides of its axis of rotation.
For the sake of abstracting away irrelevant details in order to isolate the concept being tested, let's make some assumptions:

assume there is no ether,
let the spinning top be precisely at the centre of the universe,
let nothing be spinning before the top is spun

Then according to Newtonian mechanics, the act of spinning the top throws the heavens apart.  This is because it's logical to measure the rotation of the heavens relative to reference frame in which the universe has zero rotation.  Give the spinning top, the heavens are now rotating relative to that reference frame and therefore they are thrown apart by the fact that they are not bound together and therefore what WOULD have been their own centrifugal force, encounters no mechanical resistance.
Question
Does relativity agree with Newtonian mechanics on this - does it predict the same, the opposite, or something diffferent?
I can see Mach's principle is relevant here but I can't see which side of the fence relativity sits.
Edit
I have found one reference - According to Albert Einstein, by the Einstein-Lense-Thirring effect (essentially rotation frame dragging) a central spinning top will spin the heavens thereby throwing them apart. Reference here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lense%E2%80%93Thirring_precession

Please note that there is no center of the Universe. The Universe is, and always has been, infinite as far as we can tell; this is because spacetime is roughly flat at large scales so a curve never comes back to meet itself.

@controlgroup You can be flat and have closed curves: a torus.

I doubt that that was in consideration, though. On a torus I at least would still be hard-pressed to define a “center”.

@controlgroup Mention of the "centre" was used only to abstract away any irrelevant arguments regarding the spinning top not being at the centre.  Your point does not introduce any such arguments, it says they are irrelevant.  But by my abstracting centrality away, we are able to focus upon the principle at hand without needing to lean upon your claim about the centre, nor any rebuttal of it.

Your problem is yet another example of why the concept of centrifugal effect should never be taught outside of university. There is no such thing as centrifugal force pushing the universe away. You are just confusing yourself.
The thing that is spinning, can feel and deduce that it is spinning, and thereby subtract the illusion of centrifugal effect from its deduction of what is happening to the universe. There will be no disagreement with the behaviour of the universe as described by an inertial frame.
Yes, there is an interesting discussion to be had over Mach's principle. But AFAIK, GR does not agree with Mach's principle, and thus that is that. It was an interesting idea to contemplate, but it is not modern physics.

It appears in your second paragraph that you are taking "spinning" and "not spinning" as absolute properties, a premise of which is that there is an ether with respect to which the properties of spinning and not spinning are defined.  if you disagree, can you please elucidate upon how you define the property of spinning without reference to some absolute ether?

@RobertFrost Actually it is possible for an observer to tell whether they are spinning/not spinning in a vacuum. Angular velocities can always be determined because to maintain them centripetal force must be acting on the extremities of the rotating object to keep it from falling apart. Regular linear velocities cannot be identified without respect to another body, though.

There is no æther in mainstream modern physics. Acceleration is something we actually can measure with accelerometers, some of which are so small that we can fit them inside watches and smartphones. You do not have to look outwards to know that you are accelerating because of them. That means we can figure out that we are spinning without looking outwards either. All of these are basic physics.

@controlgroup your valid point that one might devise a method to detect the effects of rotation does not rebut my claim that your model necessarily defines an aether. In fact it reinforces my claim.  This is because by your logic, one could manipulate the objects until they experienced no such force then one could deduce that their current state is the state which is in harmony with the aether. Therefore by your logic the universe has a base reference frame or ether,

@naturallyInconsistent my argument to controlgroup immediately above also makes plain the contradiction in your argument.

@RobertFrost no, you are just being extremely mistaken, and you are just insisting that your house of cards isn't falling apart. It is not a sensible physics argument, so we will not be continuing conversation on this topic.

@naturallyInconsistent by your logic one could manipulate the objects until their accelerometer experienced no force at which point one would deduce that their current state is the zero frame of rotational reference or ether.  Yet you said you did not subscribe to the notion of an ether - a contradiction.  If it were MY house of cards which were falling apart then you would have rebutted this rather than falling to the fallacy of appealing to your own authority. A scientist appeals only to the arguments and the evidence themselves.

@RobertFrost both experimentalists and theorists agree that there is no such thing as an æther in mainstream modern physics. One does not "manipulate the objects until their accelerometer experienced no force"; that is definitely not how we do things on Earth, at least. But one can transform measurements made in an accelerating frame, say on Earth, to one that is not rotating, using those accelerometers, say. In more precise words, the existence of "non-rotating frames being an absolute entity in physics" in no way implies the existence of æther. You are the one mistakenly insisting on it.

According to Albert Einstein, by the Einstein-Lense-Thirring effect (essentially rotation frame dragging) the spinning top will spin the heavens thereby throwing them apart. Reference here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lense%E2%80%93Thirring_precession

@RobertFrost That effect is literally in conflict with Mach's principle. It makes it clear that spinning objects get a spacetime that is different from non-spinning ones. It does not "thereby throwing them apart".
